# Adobe Flash Player Settings not clickable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

When I display the flash player settings panel it dosen't response to any click.

```
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA);
```

I really don't know what I cloud have messed up.

Comment: Are you on Mac? It's a known [bug](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/known-issues-mac-os-10.html). Try updating the Flash Player to the latest version and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: What playerversion did you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting the answer from the comments here to get it off of the unanswered list. If the asker or the original answerer (Strille) wants to post their answer instead of accepting this one, that is fine with me. (I'm not expecting an accept or anything.)

This problem is a known [bug](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/known-issues-mac-os-10.html) on Mac that was fixed by updating Flash Player to the latest version.

[ANSWER CREDIT GOES TO STRILLE]